# JMS Message rollback to queue

Tags: jms, rabbitmq

I got a situation where a message is consumed by consumer and an exception occurs in consumer processing. Currently we are suppressing the exception which is wrong. 
How to make sure that if an exception occurs during processing the processing the message still remains in the queue and is retried again. We haven't configured retry queue. We are using rabbit MQ.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this using TransactionManagement. if the transaction success(ie.if the messaging processing completes) you should commit the transaction else you should rollback it.once it is rollbacked the message will get automatically  pushed into the queue .And you should also use redeliverypolicy in JMS to process the message again after some specified interval of time.